# Dark Souls 3 DLCs cannot be installed on my PS4

Tags: ps4, dark-souls-3

I bought 2 DLCs for Dark Souls 3 for PS4 from Playstation Store. I downloaded them but they cannot be installed. I did not buy Dark Souls 3 from that online market, but I have physical copy. Is it a problem? How can I run those DLCs?

Comment: What error are you getting when you try to install them?

Comment: application is not found error I encounter

Comment: I believe games need to do some installation prior to playing them.  Have you started the game up before?

Comment: I finished game twice

Comment: Does your PS4 have enough free storage to install the DLCs?

Comment: yes it has like 200 gb empty space

Comment: Is the region of the physical copy and the PSN store you bought the DLC's from the same? Sometimes the DLC's have to be from the same region as the physical copy for them to work.

Answer (score 1):

[This link](https://support.us.playstation.com/articles/en_US/KC_Article/PS4-Trouble-With-Downloadable-Content) should cover most of any issues you might be having with Installing your DLC.

The potential issues are that there are some system inconsistencies with licenses, incomplete downloads causing errors with the files, or potentially something to do with your Primary PS, or simply a space issue (for some reason, the HDD management is pre-allocated based on installed applications/games, saved game data, and other things like pictures and videos).

The only other potential things are if your downloaded files do not give you the option to install (likely not what you are experiencing) you might need to [use the PS Store App](https://www.reddit.com/r/dyinglight/comments/2twf89/application_not_found_ps4/) to re-download your files.